# When gene editing are both chromosomes in a pair changed?

Tags: genetics, crispr

Sorry for the possibly confused question, my knowledge of genetics is limited to medical training only but I have a question.

Are gene editing techniques such as CRISPR used on both of the chromosomes in a pair or just on one of them?

Some of the general searching I have done suggests that it can hit one or both. Is there a preferred outcome?

Answer (score 1):

Gene editing using CRISPR-Cas9 can result in both heterozygous and homozygous conditions. It is just the event of probability. But even if u get heterozygous line, making it homozygous is not very difficult. You just have to cross two heterozygous line and screen for homozygous line through markers.

Comment: Thank you very much for the response. In general is it preferred to gain a homozygous or a hetrozygous change or is it specific to the intended task?

Comment: It is specific to the task. If homozygous is not lethal, then i would go for homozygous line, as it will be easy to maintain. In case if you maintain heterozygous, then screening at each generation is necessary.